# Using the Python C API to print asynchronously to the console

Tags: python, c, multithreading, python-2.7, python-3.4

I'm interfacing Python with the IDL programming language. I'm using the Python C API (both 2.7 and 3.4) on Windows, Linux, and Mac. The Python interpreter is running in the main thread, while IDL is running in a separate thread. I'm trying to reroute output from the IDL thread to the Python console. Here's a snippet of code:

```
PyObject *tmp;
PyGILState_STATE gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
PyObject* pyStdout = PySys_GetObject("stdout");
// buf is a null-terminated char*
PyObject* pyOutput = PyString_FromFormat("%s", buf);
PyFile_WriteObject(pyOutput, pyStdout, Py_PRINT_RAW);
Py_DECREF(pyOutput);
tmp = PyObject_CallMethod(pyStdout, "flush", NULL);
if (tmp != NULL) Py_DECREF(tmp);
PyGILState_Release(gstate);
```

The output appears on the Python console, but the Python prompt ends up somewhere in the middle. For example, printing out numbers 1-5:

```
>>> IDL.run('@batch.pro')
       1
>>>        2
       3
       4
       5
```

At this point, typing in the Python console will obliterate the last few lines of output. The results are not always consistent, and also depend on the console. Using the Windows "cmd" console, it's always messed up. Using either the IPython QTConsole or the console on Linux works a bit better, but still ends up with a prompt in the middle of the output.

I tried a different approach using print(), but it didn't help:

```
PyObject* pyBuiltIn = PyImport_ImportModule(PY_BUILTIN);
PyObject *tmp = PyObject_CallMethod(pyBuiltIn, "print", "s", buf);
if (tmp != NULL) Py_DECREF(tmp);
Py_DECREF(pyBuiltIn);
```

I get the same behavior using Python 2.7 and 3.4. Is there a different mechanism for sending output to the Python console that works asynchronously? This must be possible, because if you create a non-blocking Python widget (say using tkinter), you can successfully send output. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: @Chad Simmons just curious, why you deleted the word "Python" in the title? It seems like it needs the "Python C API", otherwise it's unclear what API it being referred to?

Comment: tags already sort it out, but I'll edit to add clarity

Comment: Don't know much of python, but from the description, it seems like you need to do your own synchronization around python console..?